# How to get the number of bytes occupied by a specific string in the program?

Tags: c++

Im using BSPlib and I want to use the bsp_put which requires me to set the size of the string I'm sending.
Even if you aren't familiar with BSP, this is not closely related. thanks.

Comment: What sort of string ? A plain c-string or String object ?

Comment: std::string? char*? what kind of string

Comment: `strlen()`, or do you mean size of the whole std::string object?

Comment: String object (c++ #include <string>)

Comment: I mean std::string, and i mean the whole object

Comment: Don't know what BSP is. But if you want to to SEND something, you probably want to send the text, didn't you? If you really want to send the object, you need a complete serialization.

Comment: std::string instance is not guaranteed to be object in continuos memory space so size in bytes makes no sense.

Comment: @Öö Tiib , yes, the organization of the string data is not guaranteed, but the organization of the memory returned by c_str() and data() is guaranteed.

Comment: `string::size` is the right one, even though you don't think so.

Comment: sizeof(char) on all systems will be guaranteed to be 1, so string::size should give you what you need.

Comment: `string::size` is the right one if you want to know, how much size does contained actual string take. `string::capacity` is the right one if you want to know the heap-size of string object. If you want total size of `string` on both stack and heap, `sizeof(std::string) + string::capacity` should be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) returns the length of string of a plain C string.

> A C string is as long as the amount of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character.

If you're using the String object you can use the `length` or `size` method of the object:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/

Comment: Of course you need to add 1, because of end-of-string char ('\0').

Comment: Why would you need to add one? `bsp_put` wants to know how many characters to send. If you don't intend to send the \0, you must not include it in the count.

Answer (score 10):

Multiply the number of characters (given by `size()`, or `capacity()` if you want to know the total amount allocated rather than the amount in use) by the size of the character type.

If it's `std::string` itself, an alias for `std::basic_string<char>`, then the character size is one byte, so `size()` (or `capacity()`) alone will do.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i just got confused for it the characters are UTF-8,16, a wide char would do it.
possibly few people here are getting confused with the byte size of the string and character size of the string..

Comment: @51k: it is you who is confused. 'std::string' means 'char'

Comment: @51k To elaborate: `std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853372/count-of-bytes-in-stdstring

Answer (score 1):

The number of characters in a std::string can be had by the "[size()"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) member of std::string.

```
std::string s = "Hey, look, I'm a string!"
std::string::size_type len = s.size();
std::cout << "My string is " << len << "characters long." << std::endl;
```

As people have pointed out, you cannot rely upon the memory organization of std::string, except for two cases: [std::string::data()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) and [std::string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). Each of these functions return a pointer to contiguous memory, which memory holds the same characters as the string. (The memory may or may not point to the *real* string, but it doesn't matter, you can't write to it anyway.) The difference between the two calls is whether the memory has a terminating null byte: `data()` has no terminating character, `c_str()` does.

```
// assuming that bsp_put_bytes takes a pointer & len
bsp_put_bytes(s.data(), s.size());

// and bsp_put_string takes a C-style string
bsp_put_string(s.c_str());
```

Carefully read the caveats in the links I gave you, including the valid lifetime of the pointed-to characters.

Comment: formally the return value of `std::string::size()` is `std::string::size_type`.

Comment: Thanks @wilhelmtell. I'd +1 you if I could.

Answer (score -4):

```
std::string myString("this is the text of my string");
const char *copyOfString = strdup(myString.c_str());
size_t myStringLength = strlen(copyOfString);
free(copyOfString);
```

That's probably the most efficient way of getting the length of the string.  Let me know how impressed your coworkers are when you show them your new solution using this example.