# Count of bytes in std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

How can I get the count of bytes occupied by the data in the `std::string`.
I do not need the count of characters but the count of bytes used by the data.
I have seen the following function, they are of no use for me.

- `string::size` – Returns the number of characters in the string.
- `string::max_size` – Returns the maximum possible number of bytes in the string.
- `string::reserve` – Reserves storage in the string
- `string::capacity` – Returns the current reservation